# shift invariant subpaces of sequence space

Tags: sequences-and-series, field-theory

I'm having trouble with proving that there are infinitely many infinite dimensional shift invariant subspaces of sequence space over the abstract field. I tried to figure out some infinite class of such subspaces, but I wasn't able to find any.

Comment: What do "sequence space" and "shift invariant" mean?

Comment: Vector space of all sequences with operations "+" and "*" where t=u+v means that t(i)=u(i)+v(i) for all natural i, and w=a*u means that w(i)=a*v(i) for all natural i and a from the field P. In this space we can define shift operator s, such as s(u)=v and v(i)=u(i+1) for all natural i. So subspace L is shift invariant if s(L) belongs to L